# What is the sequence of dojo.query()?

Tags: javascript, dojo

If I register 10 widgets with the same class, lets say '.someClass'. Now if I do `dojo.query('.someClass')`, I will get a JS array.

My question is, what will be the sequence of the widgets in that array? Will it always be the same order in which I have registered them? Or it can be random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be the same order of the DOM